# Save values of multiple select boxes with id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one or multiple select boxes for each object that I iterate through in `ng-repeat`. The user should be able to select 3 priorities out of the select boxes and save them with a button click. In the save function I want to access the object.id the select box belonged to and the choosen value.

Here is my current code with my problems and questions in comments:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <div>
        <md-input-container>
            <md-select ng-model="selectedPriority" placeholder="Priorität">
                <md-option ng-value="{{ priority.name }}+{{ object.id }}" ng-repeat="priority in priorities">{{ priority.name }}</md-option> <!--setting of ng-value throws an error? How can I do this?-->
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container><br>
        {{ object.id}}
    </div>
</div>
<md-button ng-click="save()">Save</md-button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.save = function () {
    console.log($scope.selectedPriority); //Here I want to get all object.id with selected value but it is undefined
}
```

@Sajeetharan: The object json has the following form

**JSON**

```
[{  
    "date":"2017-01-21T18:20:00.873Z",
    "duration":120,
    "location":"Test",
    "passed":false,
    "id":"58838763019ac0479455bbc0"
},
{  
    "date":"2017-01-21T15:15:00.420Z",
    "duration":10,
    "location":"Test",
    "passed":false,
    "id":"58839ac9019ac0479455bbc1"
}
//...]
```

Comment: post your objects json

Comment: what is priorities array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

Initialize selectedPriority as empty array:

```
$scope.selectedPriority = [ ];
```

Use ng-change to reflect changes onto selectedPriority, only to access them in save function.

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <div>
        <md-input-container>

            <md-select ng-model="selectedPriority[$index].priority" placeholder="Priorität" ng-change=" selectedPriority[$index].objectId = object.id">
                <md-option ng-value="priority.name" ng-repeat="priority in priorities">{{ priority.name }}</md-option> <!--setting of ng-value throws an error? How can I do this?-->
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container><br>
        {{ object.id}}
    </div>
</div>
<md-button ng-click="save()">Save</md-button>
```

and then access selectedPriority:

```
$scope.save = function(){
    // use $scope.selectedPriority[neededIndex].objectId ;
    // use $scope.selectedPriority[neededIndex].priority ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use like this: `ng-value="{{ priority.name }}+{{ object.id }}"`

You have to separate them: `ng-model="object.selectedPriority"` and `ng-value="priority"`. 
Finally on save button click: make loop to print each object's selected priority.

I assumed your `priorities` array is a bunch of objects with `name` keys.
Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRPbdq

Sorry If I got wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can pass an array to the `ng-model` directive, but the trick here is to use the appropriate index.

You need to change your HTML as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects track by $index">
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedPriority[$index]">
      <option ng-repeat="priority in priorities" value="{{ priority.name }}+{{ object.id }}">{{priority}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, we're using a scope variable `selectedPriority`, which is declared as an array.

Now, if you just console `$scope.selectedPriority` on the button's click, you will get an array with the values you desired.